# Is it possible for Texstudio to locate the source line corresponding to a given line in the preview?

Tags: texstudio, forward-inverse-search

I know that Texstudio will automatically highlight in the preview the line generated by the source line lastly-modified before preview, and this function is really convenient for many purposes.

However, I need to do that reversely in some circumstances where errors are caught afterwards. In such a case, it would be wonderful to be able to find the corresponding source line rapidly by clicking the lines where the errors were found.

Comment: Did you try it? Clicking on the pdf to go to the source works fine with sumatra and I would have expected that texstudio can do it out-of-box too.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I tried and found not. :) Would you mind explaining it in more detail, maybe as an answer?

Comment: I just tried in texstudio: I can right click on the preview and there is a "go to source" entry in the context menu.

Comment: Oh my, thanks. It turns out that I just tried the left click... Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use context menu "Go To Source" or `Ctrl+LeftClick`.